# Create a function/query which matches the value with their previous value in POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

In my DB I have a table that records all the values from a specific field inside a UI. So, this table has the history of all the values from fields in the UI.

For example:

[image]

I need to create a query to let us see the new value with the previous value. For example:

[image]

Is there a way to create a query or function on PostgreSQL who can help us here?

Comment: Could be possible, but the example provided does not cover the logic that you want to achieve. What's the expected output when it changed multiple times? For whatever reason you are trying to create this query, I recommend you to just get all values available for the particular field sorted by date and then let the UI/display layer decide how to showcase it.

Comment: Most likely you’re looking for a window function like lag()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.timestamp, t1.field_tag AS new_column,
    CASE 
        WHEN t1.field_tag = t2.field_tag THEN 'No change'
        ELSE 'Change response. New value: ' || t1.field_tag || '. Old value: ' || t2.field_tag
    END AS change_response
FROM your_table t1
LEFT JOIN your_table t2 ON t1.timestamp > t2.timestamp AND t1.field_tag <> t2.field_tag
GROUP BY t1.timestamp, t1.field_tag, t2.field_tag
ORDER BY t1.timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: Note that this query assumes that each field_tag value is unique per timestamp. If this is not the case, you may need to modify the query accordingly.

Comment: please explain what you did, so that others can follow and adept it